# Where is the Speed Unit option in Update Traffic Data tool of ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, network-analyst

I can't find the Speed Unit option in the Update Traffic Data tool for ArcGIS 10.2.0 (Enterprise). In [the help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004800000022000000) Esri describes that you can specify a Speed Unit but I don't see the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the GP tool dialog it's the last parameter at the bottom of the dialog. Perhaps you need to scroll down or enlarge the dialog box to see it? Or perhaps the Enterprise interface is different, but I wouldn't think so.

[image]